# Extracting metadata (author, creation date ...) from word documents with R

Tags: r

I would like to extract the metadata (author, creation date ...) from a batch of MS word documents with R. Can anybody tell me if that is possibile, and if so how I can do this?

Thanks,
Fred.

Comment: This question doesn't appear to be on topic here.

Comment: What type of word document? XML Document or Binary format?

Comment: Standard MS Word Documents. As far as I know these are XML based.

Comment: @Fred there's no such thing as "standard MS Word Documents"

Comment: @Carl, I mean documents as output form MS Word.

Comment: @Fred, and I repeat: there is no standard.  Take a look at your output options, which include .txt, .doc, .docx,.docm, .xml, .rtf, .wps, and more.

Answer (score 0):

If you know how to use Microsoft Word's VB Properties,  then `R2Wd:wdGetProperty` can be used to pull the info of interest.

All the same, I'd recommend reading the responses to  [read an MSWord file into R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11111207/read-an-msword-file-into-r)