# Convert MS Word data into excel or dataframe in R

Tags: r, excel, ms-word

I have about 10,000 seperate MS Word doc files which contain information like ID, Patient Name, Age, Gender, Diagnosis (The example image). How could I automatically transfer these data into excel or data frame in R? Thanh you very much!

I have no idea how to make it happen. Manual copy and paste seems unbelievable! I have a basic understanding of functions in R, so if someone could do it in R, it would be a tremendous help.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YkFT2.png)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11111207/read-an-msword-file-into-r

Comment: I would try with the `officer` package to read the documents and get a summary of the content as a data frame using e.g. `docx_summary`. Still this requires some additional data cleaning and processing.